# Database export from google cloud sql to google cloud storage on GCP taking too long

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I have postgres database of 1 TB data on google cloud sql region south-east-asia which I am exporting to google cloud storage bucket archival storage class resides in region US, its been more than 30 hours and in operation tab of sql instance on gcp it is showing "Exporting data to gs://archived-sql-data/Cloud_SQL_Export_2023-08-03 (15:14:30).sql"

I want to find out how long will it take as it is unusual to take this long and how can I find percentage of completion like how far it is in the export process as I doubt that it has stuck or something